# Добавление строки в таблицу jquery

Tags: html, jquery

Есть таблица в форме.

```
for($i=1; $i<=6; $i++){
                    echo "\t<tr class="product_table" >\n";
                    echo "\t  <td><input class=\"goods\" type=\"text\" name=\"goods" . $i . "\" value=\"" . $_POST['goods' . $i] . "\"/></td>\n";
                    echo "\t  <td class=\"center\"><input name=\"kod" . $i . "\" value=\"" . $_POST['kod' . $i] ."\" type=\"text\" size=\"10\"></td>\n";
                    echo "\t  <td class=\"center\"><input name=\"qantity" . $i . "\" value=\"" . $_POST['qantity' . $i] . "\" type=\"text\" size=\"10\" /></td>\n";
                    echo "\t  <td class=\"center\"><input name=\"price" . $i . "\" value=\"" . $_POST['price' . $i] . "\" type=\"text\" size=\"10\" /></td>\n";
                    echo "\t  <td class=\"center\"><input name=\"cvet" . $i . "\" value=\"" . $_POST['cvet' . $i] . "\" type=\"text\" size=\"10\" /></td>\n";
                    echo "\t  <td class=\"center\"><input name=\"litera" . $i . "\" value=\"" . $_POST['litera' . $i] . "\" type=\"text\" size=\"10\" /></td>\n";

                    echo "\t</tr>\n";
                }
```

Никак не могу разобраться как с помощью jquery добавлять новые строки в таблицу.

```
$('.product_table:last').after('<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>');
```

Не срабатывает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.product_table:last')
```

Если я не ошибаюсь, то данный селектор выберет саму таблицу в итоге. Надо :

```
$('.product_table tr:last')
```

Comment: Ошибку в вопросе допустил, нет .product_table и есть <tr>

Comment: Просто все равно странно называть класс product_table и присваивать его к tr =). Попробуй тогда `$('.product_table').last().after(...tdblocks..)` или ` $(...tdblocks...).insertAfter('.product_table:last) '

Comment: да заработало, спс.

Comment: `$('.product_table:last').after('<tr><td><input class="goods" type="text" name="goods" value=""></td> <td class="center"><input name="kod" value="" type="text" size="10"></td> <td class="center"><input name="qantity" value="" type="text" size="10" /></td> <td class="center"><input name="price" value="" type="text" size="10" /></td> <td class="center"><input name="comments" value="" type="text" size="38" /></td> </tr>');` Вот так сделал, есть только 1 проблема, можно ли в этой же команде любой name присваивать переменную?

Comment: Т.е если бы через пхп бы я делал `echo '<input class="goods" type="text" name="goods'.$var1.'"' `>

Comment: ну конкатенацию строк никто не отменял - поэтому можно. Т.е. `<td name='goods"+someVar+" '>` . Только смотри внимательно за кавычками